# Custom association for Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to define a relation between 2 models `Customer` and `CustomerProduct`, linking `customer.custom_id` on `customerproduct.customer_id` so that `mycustomer.customer_products.create()` ends up with `customerproduct.customer_id = customer.custom_id` instead of `customer.id`.

This is my Customer model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organisation
  has_many :customer_products, foreign_key: 'customer_id'
end
```

And my CustomerProduct model:

```
class CustomerProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

I'm not sure how to define the `custom_id` bit - I tried adding it as a foreign key in `belongs_to :customer` but this doesn't seem to do anything - Rails still takes `customer.id`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Let's just say the answer was quite obvious so I must have been blind!

```
has_many :customer_products, primary_key: 'custom_id', foreign_key: 'customer_id'
```

Comment: This is true *if* the `customer_id` is the primary key, but you didn't say that it was in your question. Thus my prior comment was based upon `customer_id` being "just another attribute".